# How to annualize alpha calculated from a daily regression?

Tags: finance

forgive the super beginner question. I have the following code. bench_return_data and my_return data contain daily returns. I am performing a linear regression between them. Am I calculating annualized alpha correctly? Should I be raising it to the 252th power or just multiplying it by 252, or am I completely off?

```
m, b = np.polyfit(bench_return_data, my_return_data, 1)
plt.plot(bench_return_data, m * bench_return_data + b)
plt.scatter(bench_return_data, my_return_data, c = np.arange(len(my_return_data)))

print("Beta: {}    Annualized alpha: {}".format(m, (1 + b) ** 252 - 1))
```

Comment: Personally for "annualized daily alpha" I just multiply by 252.

Comment: Note that  your other formula is the compounded version of the formula for going from the daily to the annual. if you're not assuming compounding, then I agree with @noob2 that you should just multiply by 252.

Comment: Well, I wonder whether I should assume compounding or not. Sometimes considering extreme cases can be helpful. So I thought, If I had an impossible alpha just for the sake of example of, say, 10% per day, that would make me the richest person in the world. In that case I probably should assume compounding, because if I don't, the calculation would not make clear just how much money I'm making.

But I'm not sure whether this reasoning is principled. I could have the same alpha but with two very different volatilities and the higher the volatility the less money I'd make, right?

Comment: Hi Whether you: compound or not depends on the context. If the returns are from one position that's getting you that return every day, then don't compound. If it's from a different position each day that you're liquidating every day, then compounding is more reasonable. Either way, I wouldn't assume 10 percent a day. That's too high. With smaller numbers ( basis points ), it will make less of a difference whether you compound or not.

Comment: @markleeds the 10 percent was just to make an extremely extreme example and maybe gain some insight from it. Feel free to put your comment as an answer so I can accept it.

Comment: @Eugenio Bruno: Gotcha on the 10 percent. I think noob2 should put his as an answer because he really answered the question. I was just commenting on the implications of the formula you wrote. But thanks for offer.